# Reading workouts data from FIT file

Tags: c#, mapmyfitness

Hello I am trying read data from .fit extension file from c#.
I need to fetch workouts data from that file.

I have some sample files using and I am using idk at https://www.thisisant.com/resources/fit

I am unable to find any sort of documentation or any.

Any sort of guidance in this regards will be helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you head to their page (https://www.thisisant.com/resources/fit/), and click the "I agree" button on the bottom, you'll get a zip with a whole bunch of PDF explaining what's what, plus some code examples for C# (and c,cpp, java as well).

What is it exactly you can't find ?